# Require seems to be causing module not found for a module that exsists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently trying to implement a background that changes depending on the props received by the component but much of what I try seems to cause error or just not show a background at all.

The only way I seem to be able to set the background in react is by typing in the path inside the url(). Any other way of trying to build a string (like adding the image name at the end of a common path) and placing in or just having the string passed as one of the props in the component seem not to work.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
  getBackgroundURL () {
    var imageUrl = this.state.game.backgroundUrl;
    return { backgroundImage: "url(" + require(imageUrl) + ")" };

  };
```

This is the error received by latest attempt:
"Error: Cannot find module '(aCorrectPath).jpg'

Thanks for the help if you have any workaround to this.

After some comments thought I should add some other things I have tried but did not work.

```
  getBackgroundURL () {
    var imageUrl = `../resources/${this.getGameName(false)}BackGround.jpg`;
    return { backgroundImage: "url(" + require(imageUrl) + ")" };
  };
```

This one leads to the same error above.
Without using Require I just receive no background image at all.

**The only thing that seems to work**

```
  getBackgroundURL () {
    return { backgroundImage: "url(" + require("../resources/GameNameBackGround.jpg") + ")" };
  };
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `require` here? I mean if the backgroundUrl is just path which has to be contained in final styles isn't possible to use just `{ backgroundImage: "url(" + imageUrl + ")" }`?

Comment: Why not use relative path instead of require, such like ``../path/to/folder/${imageUrl}``

Comment: @JaxCze without the require I seem get an empty background

Updated my question with some examples of what I tried.

Comment: @SultanH. Tried that but see to have the same problem.
Updated my question to include of attempts I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution,
After looking back at relative paths based on the comments. The following code worked:

```
  getBackgroundURL () {
    return { backgroundImage: "url(" + require(`../resources/${this.getGameName(false)}BackGround.jpg`) + ")" };
  };
```

The difference between this and an attempt made above is that. The relative path is put inside the function instead of in a variable and putting the variable in the return.

Not sure what difference this makes but it worked. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You may mark this as the correct answer for the questions  to let others who seem to have related problem figure out this as a possible solution to thiers, good job!